# Which initializers are affected by tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1,
                                                0.1)
with tf.name_scope("Train"):
    with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
         model = network.Model(iterator, is_training=True)
```

My question is which variables are affected by the initializer I am passing in the variable_scope? Embedding matrices are definitely affected because I use `tf.get_variable` to create the matrix with `None` passed as an initializer. But what about `tf.layers.Conv2D`? If I leave the `kernel_initializer=None` which is the default, is it going to use the default initializer I use in the variable scope?

I am using TF 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. And you can check it with

```py
initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.1, 0.1)
with tf.variable_scope("Model", reuse=None, initializer=initializer):
    model = tf.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=1)

print(model.get_config())
```

If you'd like to set some parameters to many layers at once you can use arg_scope, although it's from soon to be deprecated contrib module

Comment: This doesn't really show what initializer is used. It just says `kernel_initializer=None`. I still don't know which one is going to be used internally. The default one from the variable scope or something else like `glorot_uniform`?

Comment: The default is `glorot_uniform` This only shows that it will use default and not the one, provided with scope

Comment: Change the initializer to `random_normal_initializer`. Then try adding the line `model.build([64,32,32,1])`. Then `print(model.kernel)` and you will see that it's using the normal initializer.

Comment: How should i be able to see that from a line like `<tf.Variable 'conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1, 1, 3) dtype=float32_ref>`?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say `model.kernel.initializer`

Comment: Still, it will only use the specified initializer only if you explicitly pass it to `kernel_initializer`. Don'n know exactly why it uses normal_uniform after build.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable
"If initializer is None (the default), the default initializer passed in the variable scope will be used. If that one is None too, a glorot_uniform_initializer will be used."
If it uses `tf.get_variable` internally then I don't see how you could be right. Are you sure that it always uses glorot_uniform when it is None?

Comment: As I said earlier, and you just quoted from docs, glorot is the default initializer.  
layer.build doesn't have `get_default_initializer` which `get_variable` uses. So, for some reason, it uses `normal_uniform`.

Comment: I have run some more tests without using `build()`. After I initialize the variables using `session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` I get a handle to one of the kernels inside my model using `conv_checking = [v for v in tf.global_variables() if v.name == 'Model/EncoderCNN/conv2d_2/kernel:0'][0]`. Then just do `print(conv_checking.initializer)` and you can see that it becomes random_normal if the initializer of the variable scope is set to `random_normal_initializer`. Thanks for your help anyway